# Insert/update row /Import from XML via Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I am parsing an XML document to a database, and I am looking for an effective variant for my code. `ITEM_ID` is unique, but the code keeps adding new rows to the database and won't update existing rows.

This is an example of the source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SHOP>
<SHOPITEM>
<ITEM_ID>8159</ITEM_ID>
<PRODUCT></PRODUCT>
<DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
<URL>http://www.domovhracek.cz/</URL>
<IMGURL>http://www.domovhracek.cz/css/images/beznahledusmall.png</IMGURL>
<EAN></EAN>
<PRICE>2391</PRICE>
<CATEGORYTEXT>zaradit</CATEGORYTEXT>
<MANUFACTURER>Domov hraček</MANUFACTURER>
<PRICE_VAT>2893.00</PRICE_VAT>
<DELIVERY_DATE>0</DELIVERY_DATE>
</SHOPITEM>
</SHOP>
```

This is the source of the importing controller:

```
class ImportController < ApplicationController
  def importer
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'nokogiri'
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.domovhracek.cz/feed/heureka.xml"))
    doc.css('SHOPITEM').each do |node|
    children = node.children
    @conditions={:ITEM_ID=> children.css('ITEM_ID').inner_text}
    begin
      record = ShopItem.find(:first, :conditions => {:ITEM_ID=>children.css('ITEM_ID').inner_text} )
      record.PRODUCT=children.css('PRODUCT').inner_text
      record.DESCRIPTION=children.css('DESCRIPTION').inner_text

      record.save
    rescue
      record= ShopItem.create({:ITEM_ID=> children.css('ITEM_ID').inner_text})
      record.PRODUCT=children.css('PRODUCT').inner_text
      record.DESCRIPTION=children.css('DESCRIPTION').inner_text
      record.save
    end
  end
end
```

If I find the key `ITEM_ID` I will update my record but my code inserts a new row everytime .

Comment: well excuse my english , goal of script is  insert new row if i am wont find in column ITEM_ID given value from XML node otherwise update that found row from atributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use a loop like this to walk through your XML:

```
doc.search('SHOPITEM').each do |shop_item|
  item_id = shop_item.at('ITEM_ID').text
  product = shop_item.at('PRODUCT').text
  description = shop_item.at('DESCRIPTION').text
  # ...
end
```

Each iteration that finds a `<SHOPITEM>` tag will gather the information to create/modify a row.

Instead of using `css`, which is equivalent to `search`, you should use `at` or `at_css`. Both `css` and `search` return a NodeSet, which is like an array. If you use `inner_text` on a NodeSet that contains more than one node, you'll get all the text nodes concatenated together as a string, which is most likely not what you want and will usually be a bug you have to fix:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<foo>
  <bar>1</bar>
  <bar>2</bar>
</foo>
EOT

doc.search('bar').inner_text # => "12"
doc.css('bar').inner_text # => "12"
```

For more information, read the documentation for `css`, `search`, `at` and `at_css` in the [Nokogiri::XML::Node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html) page, along with the `inner_text` documentation in the [Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html) page.